# Create Tree Given Component Nodes and Operators

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Quite new to tree Data Structures. I am given 2 variables `rules` and `operators`. Each of them is a list of strings. For example:

```
op = ['&',"|","&"]
rules = ['a','b','c','d']
```

The `len(op)` has to always equal `len(rules)-1` because `op` always connect rules or another `op`.

So in the above, a possible tree is:

```
     "|"
   /      \
"&"        "&"
 |  \      |   \
 "a" "b"  "c"  "d"
```

Another possible one is

```
         "&"
       /     \
     "|"      "d"
   /      \
"&"        "c"
 |  \     
 "a" "b"
```

An invalid tree:

```
"c"
 |   \
"|"  "d"
```

The above tree is not valid because another above an operator cannot be a rule.

Now as the number of rules and operators increase, there are going to be endless combinations of trees. My question is whether it is possible to generate the above trees randomly? Is there an algorithm for this? More specifically, is there a way to randomly create binary trees given you know what the nodes and leafs must be?

Thanks

Comment: If you know what the nodes and leaves must be where does the randomness come in?

Comment: in the tree structure as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of this:

1- shuffle your rules: e.g. `['a','b','c','d']` -> `['c','a','b','d']` (or if you can have repeated and "missing" rules just make a random selection such as `['c','d','b','b','d']` with desired length)

2- make each rule in the list a "singleton" tree (i.e. just a leaf), e.g. `'a'` -> `Tree('a', None, None)`

3- pick a random index `i` in `range(len(rules)-1)`

4- pick a random operator `oper` from `op` (same here, either shuffle `op` then take elements one by one from the list, or just select a random one independently every time, depending on what you want... )

5- replace the 2 elements at `rules[i:i+2]` with a new single element `Tree(oper, rules[i], rules[i+1])`

6- repeat from step 3 until `len(rules) == 1`

7- you now have a random tree

Comment: I don't quiet understand 5.

Comment: `rules = [r_0, r_1, ... , r_(i-1), r_(i), r_(i+1), r_(i+2), ...]` becomes `rules = [r_0, r_1, ... , r_(i-1), Tree(oper, r_(i), r_(i+1)), r_(i+2), ...]` (Note that at this stage `rules` only contains tree objects already, all the `r_j` are trees...)

Comment: another question I have is whether you have a way to generate trees that that when evaluated gives bounded results. thats a problem I am facing and unsure of how to solve. Put another way, think about Operators in the above taking values ['-','+','*','/'] and rules are now numbers or variables.  How can i make sure the tree, when solved yields results that are bounded?

Comment: Generate, Evaluate, Check if within bound, Repeat otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my crack at a solution. I decided to split the algorithm into two parts. First I generated a random tree structure using the operators. Then I went through and added the terminals to the current leaf nodes.

```
op = ['&',"|","+"]
terminals = ['a','b','c','d']

shuffle(op)
shuffle(terminals)



class tree:
    def __init__(self, l, r, v):
        self.left = l
        self.right = r
        self.value = v


root = tree(None, None, op[0])
op.pop(0)
def createNonTerminals(root):
    if len(op) == 0:
        return
    choice = randint(0,1)
    if choice == 0: #binary
        root.left = tree(None, None, op[0])
        op.pop(0)
        if len(op) > 0:
            root.right = tree(None, None, op[0])
            op.pop(0)
            createNonTerminals(root.right)
            createNonTerminals(root.left)

        else:
            createNonTerminals(root.left)
    else:
        choice = randint(0, 1)
        if choice == 1:
            root.right = tree(None, None, op[0])
            op.pop(0)
            createNonTerminals(root.right)
        else:
            root.left = tree(None, None, op[0])
            op.pop(0)
            createNonTerminals(root.left)

def addNonTerminals(root):
    if root.left == None:
        root.left = tree(None, None, terminals[0])
        terminals.pop(0)
    else:
        addNonTerminals(root.left)
    if root.right == None:
        root.right = tree(None, None, terminals[0])
        terminals.pop(0)
    else:
        addNonTerminals(root.right)
```

Here is some example outputs

```
['+']
['&', 'd']
['~', 'f']
['a', '-']
['e', '|']
['b', 'c']

['|']
['&', '~']
['+', '-', 'b', 'a']
['d', 'f', 'e', 'c']
```